# Separating the addition of different fields under the same key

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a way to add new fields with the same key, but independently of each other? I want both groups to be added using Enter.
Currently, fields with values are added with Enter, groups with Shift.

My actual code in form:

```
<div id="parent" class="list-group">
                    <div class="form-group form-filed horizontal">
                        <input name="values[]" class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter value"
                            autofocus onkeypress='validate(event)' onkeydown="pressEnter(event)" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="parent" class="list-group">
                    <div class="form-group form-filed horizontal">
                        <input name="groups[]" class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter group"
                            autofocus onkeypress='validate(event)' onkeydown="pressEnter(event)" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function pressEnter(evt){    
    if(evt.which==13)
      addDivValue();
    if(evt.which==16)
      addDivGroup();
  }

  function addDivValue(){
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className= 'form-group form-filed horizontal';   

    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.placeholder='Enter value';
    input.type='text';
    input.className='input';
    input.autocomplete='off';
    input.name= 'values[]';
    input.required=true;
    input.addEventListener("keypress",validate);
    input.addEventListener("keydown", pressEnter);

    newDiv.appendChild(input);
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parent");
    parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
    input.focus();
  }

  function addDivGroup(){
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className= 'form-group form-filed horizontal';   

    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.placeholder='Enter group';
    input.type='text';
    input.className='input';
    input.autocomplete='off';
    input.name= 'groups[]';
    input.required=true;
    input.addEventListener("keypress",validate);
    input.addEventListener("keydown", pressEnter);

    newDiv.appendChild(input);
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parent");
    parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
    input.focus();
  }
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do but I think you need to `clone` the `parent` div if so just use `cloneNode` in javascript
and you shouldn't use `id` in that case use `class` instead.

Comment: I will write it as easily as possible: press Enter -> add new value field, pres Enter -> add new value field... Analogous to groups: press Enter -> add group field...